# Two Related field populated each other using cascading

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, workflow

I have two columns in SharePoint list, both are drop down. Those are the main category field, which is hidden field and the sub category.

when user is going to select from the sub category list, the main category drop down should be populated based on the sub category drop down.

NB:

I tried cascading drop down, But I can't . May be does Workflow do it ?

Answer (score 0):

SPServices offers a Cascading Dropdown feature that will do what you are looking for.  Here is a great article on [how to do it](http://www.bentedder.com/sharepoint-sketches-spservices-cascading-dropdowns/).  You can grab the library from [here](https://spservices.codeplex.com/releases/view/119578). This is going to be your best bet.  You could use CSOM and jQuery to get the selected index and query the next, but SPServices does it for you.  Why re-invent the wheel :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to accomplish this without code is to consider utilizing a Managed Metadata column. While it's not going to simulate a cascading dropdown, it will allow you to group things together in a hierarchical manner that a user can see when making a selection. (i.e. your top-level categories would be at one level, and you'd embed the sub categories under their respective parent)

You'll also have the ability to roll up to the parent level if needed, if you're looking to create views that consolidate only on a top-level area.

Cheers,
Matt