# Cascading drop down(Edited)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, infopath

I got a problem in cascading drop down, so i need to select a value from one drop down depends on another one.

I have two fields(Health location and Health Sub-location) . Both are item retrieved from the "keyList" which is data connect from "keyList".

So, When user select item from the drop down of "Health Sub-location" field, The Health location field will populate item based on the selected "Health Sub-location"

[Two Related field populated each other using cascading](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/224345/two-related-field-populated-each-other-using-cascading/224346#224346)

NB:

- Health Sub-location has 100 item in his drop drown
- Health location has 7 item in his drop down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some information I posted [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/224345/two-related-field-populated-each-other-using-cascading-or-workflow/224346#224346).  SPServices has a great, easy to set up Cascading Dropdown feature you can use.  I use it quite a bit

Comment: Thanks Lazo , Do you know any option in Out-Of-The Box? If not , I can Try SPService cascading

Comment: @Sara unfortunately there is no out-of-the-box solution for cascading drop-downs.  You can use SPServices, or else write your own custom  code to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dylan for prompt respond. Let me try to using SPService cascading. Appreciated